# Subquery in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in MySQL named OrderDetails as follows.

```
Delivered   |OrderID    |ProductID  |Quantity
true        |10001      |11         |12
true        |10002      |10         |10
true        |10002      |11         |5
false       |10002      |12         |9
true        |10002      |13         |40
true        |10003      |10         |10
true        |10003      |11         |35
true        |10003      |12         |15
false       |10004      |10         |6
false       |10004      |11         |15
true        |10004      |12         |20
false       |10005      |10         |40
false       |10005      |11         |25
true        |10005      |12         |40
false       |10005      |13         |20
```

I can get the highest order of a product then farther filter it out by it delivery status using following query.

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(Quantity) as MaxQuantity, ProductID, OrderID, Delivered FROM OrderDetails GROUP BY ProductID) as t WHERE t.Delivered = true;`

```
Delivered   |OrderID    |ProductID  |Quantity
true        |10250      |11         |35
true        |10252      |12         |40
true        |10249      |13         |40
```

I want to the same in dynamodb. I create the table where I use ProductID as primary (partition key) and Quantity as sort key. I believe the data will store as follows.

```
Delivered   |OrderID    |ProductID  |Quantity
false       |10252      |10         |40
false       |10248      |10         |10
true        |10250      |10         |10
false       |10251      |10         |6
true        |10250      |11         |35
false       |10252      |11         |25
false       |10251      |11         |15
true        |10247      |11         |12
true        |10248      |11         |5
true        |10252      |12         |40
true        |10251      |12         |20
true        |10250      |12         |15
false       |10249      |12         |9
true        |10249      |13         |40
false       |10253      |13         |20
```

Now I want to make the same kind of query in dynamodb. I have no clue to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hive to execute the same query over dynamodb. To do that:

1. Go to emr in aws console and launch a cluster.
2. Connect to the master node and type "hive".
3. In hive, create an external table linked to your dynamodb table.

   `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE OrderDetails (Delivered boolean , OrderID bigint , ProductID bigint , Quantity bigint) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES ( "dynamodb.table.name" = "OrderDetails" , "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "Delivered:Delivered , OrderID:OrderID , ProductID:ProductID , Quantity:Quantity");`
4. Execute your query in hive.

   `SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(Quantity) as MaxQuantity, ProductID, OrderID, Delivered FROM OrderDetails GROUP BY ProductID) t WHERE t.Delivered = true;`

Comment: This will work. But `hive` does not meet the performance we expected.

Comment: I don't know what performance you are expecting or your use case. You may considerer that the query you want to do needs to do an scan in dynamodb, so if you want to use this query for a web application serving response in a few miliseconds maybe dynamodb will not be the best choice in this way.